# Laravel 5.8 throws "Target [Illuminate\Database\Seeder] is not instantiable." on db:seed

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8, laravel-seeding

The title basically summarises the question, but here's what I tried.

`database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` is truncated to it's bare form - no `use`s and the `call()` method is commented. Still, I cannot run the command successfully. The problem seems to be coming from `use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;` at the top ([link to laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c4a7a7bc9cdccd00d6fdda8846d1660a0608d7ef/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php#L3)).

Running `composer dump-autoload` (even with `-o` option) doesn't resolve the issue. The version of Laravel I'm using is 5.8, which (as I've seen the bare `DatabaseSeeder` class on github) doesn't need to be namespaced, so namespacing turns out not to be the solution.

As a "stock Laravel utility" (if I may say so), it shouldn't need any additional setting-up (I mean adding to providers, `bind()`-ing and so on). Not sure if that's a direction I should take.

**Edit:** The seeder runs correctly when I set a `--class` argument. If I run `php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder` it returns a success message. The thing is that I have more than 30 seeder classes and running them one by one everytime (I need to seed the table quite often because some of the configuration files are stored in the database with seeding) is not an option.

**Edit 2:** As I am not allowed to post the original contents of the `DatabaseSeeder.php` file, here is a stripped down version of it:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use CustomLocalPackage\Database\Seeds\UsersTableSeeder;
/* About 30 more use-s */

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UsersTableSeeder::class,
            /* About 30 more classes */
        ]);
    }
}
```

Would be glad, if anyone can tell me what might be causing this issue and give me some directions on resolving it.

Comment: Can you share your `DatabaseSeeder` code?

Comment: 1) just 30 runs of each seeder is no more than 5 minutes and you will find class which cause problem.
2) usually I write run function like: run(){
$this->call(A::class);
$this->call(B::class); }  // I mean I not adding all of them in single array
3) have you tried php artisan optimize   ?